# Netbeans 8.2 Maven , ошибка при добавлении зависимости(код 501)

Tags: maven, netbeans

Начал работать с Maven (pom.xml в частности) и решил установить JUnit 4.12 , однако после того как я добавляю его в pom.xml (dependencies) то во время загрузки выходит ошибка:

[image]

Проблема заключается в том , что, репозитории с зависимостями перекочевал с http в https, и старая версия не может сама настроить и скачать. Я пробовал разные способы из английского stackoverflow
(в частности этот:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031044/how-to-change-mavens-remote-repository-url-in-the-netbeans-ide-from-http-to-ht)
Где пробовал добавить

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Но не помогло, я даже скачал последнюю версию Maven'а , однако проблема осталась.

Если кто сталкивался? Я полагаю что всё ведёт к тому чтобы я обновился до Apache NetBeans, однако уверен что есть способ решения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: надо добавить файл settings.xml, сначала попробуйте сразу создать её в корневой папке Maven'a
(Но если NetBeans не читает его, то попробуйте данный метод: создайте, или удалите всё с корневой папки Maven из папки repository при этом сделайте бэкап если NetBeans не сможет сам восстановить, и снова в ту же папку перекиньте) После этого у вас везде появится settings.xml и туда прописываем:

```
<mirrors>
<mirror>
      <id>mirror1</id>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
      <name>mirror1</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
</mirror>
    </mirrors>
```

Создаём новый проект , и всё должно заработать